# jQuery advanced selector troubles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 5 elements with the id="container1", "container2", "container3"...
I want to check if these elements are empty and if so, hide them.
I have tried many times without success. 
This was one of them:

```
$(":contains('#container'):empty").hide();
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: `$("[id^=container]:empty").hide();` try this

Comment: @Pekka Simply great! Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$("[id^=container]:empty").hide();`

> Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

[Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)